# iOS custom view across all view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I would like to have custom view set in one screen and have it across all view controllers in my application.

I find solution with using Container view. So I create `RootViewController` and I give it Container view and set my original `MainViewController` as embed in container. I added view to `RootViewController` and in first view controller (`MainViewController`) it looks good.

The problem is when I go to another view controller by Push segue. New view controllers covers whole screen (which is okay) and covers custom view too. I was thinking that it could help if I add Navigation Controller with root `MainViewController` and this navigation controller would be embed in `RootViewController` but the result is same. I set Navigation bar as hidden (same for status bar) because I want to be hidden.

So where could be problem? Or how would you add custom view to all screens? This custom view should work as global (I am using `NSTimer` and counting time) so I solution with inheritance isn't for me.

Comment: You can create a singleton for your timer (and\or even for your view) and use some base view controller, where you can add this view programmatically. Or you can add strong property in `appDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use application window and add this custom view as subview whenever required. I have used it in one of my app to show notifications (if there area any) and it works great.

Get handle to Application Window and add subview to it. Custom view can be created from a singleton class or App delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it the other way round. Make a view which will never change inside your root view controller and a container view and just change the content of the container view depending what u want to display next to your unchanging view.